# The first Chinese word always becomes a question mark, what is wrong with my mathematica?

Tags: front-end

I made a gif to show my problem. You can see, the first word I type always becomes a question mark, what is wrong? I am using version 10.3.

At first, there is no such problem, it shows up recently, I don't know what I have triggered.

[image]

Comment: What does Cell > Show Expression show you?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"?", "\:4e48?\:4e8b"}]], "Input",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.6583964943458986`*^9, 3.658396495359625*^9}}]

Comment: Does the solution [here](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/3912897995) help?

Comment: @xzczd Actually, I just found it automatically back to normal after so many days, I have no idea what has happened ╮(╯▽╰)╭